# Dynamic Breadcrumbs in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a problem concerning a breadcrumb navigation.
In my application i have a Start.aspx where i build a navigation menu for the next module (control1.ascx, control2.ascx, ...)  which should be loaded after clicking.
This ascx contains a grid with some data rows and link buttons to load other ascx on the start page
This is the common way the app works.

Now i need to visualize which ascx is loaded in the breadcrumb
Maybe we can viaualize it like this:

Start.aspx -> control1.ascx -> control1_1.ascx

Right now the app would be on the lowest level and if i click on "control1.ascx" this control should be loaded again or if i choose Start.aspx the "Home" should be loaded.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {

        NavigationDataTable moduleNameList = new NavigationDataTable();
        List<usp_GetNavigationElements_Result> ModuleList = moduleNameList.GetModulesList(1, LoggedInUser);
        StringBuilder sbResult1 = new StringBuilder();
        //string sbResult;



        if (Page.Items["title"] != null)
        {
            string id = Page.Items["title"].ToString();
            PageTitle = Page.Items["title"].ToString();
        }

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection coll;
        // Load ServerVariable collection into NameValueCollection object.
        coll = request.ServerVariables;            
        string serverName = request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"];

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        string strDomain = "";
        if (serverName == "localhost")
        {
            //Lokal
            strDomain = "localhost:49573";
        }
        else
        {
            //Intranet
            strDomain = "i";
        }

        string strURL = "/Start.aspx";
        string strDirs = "control1.ascx";

        Separator3 = new Image();            

        Separator3.Height = 52;
        Separator3.Width = 52;

        ArrowSeparator = new Image();
        ArrowSeparator.ImageUrl = "/img/mb_arrow_separator.png";

        HomeSymbol = new Image();
        HomeSymbol.ImageUrl = "/img/mb_home.png";


        // Home-Navigation for Start           
        sbResult1.Append("<img src='" + HomeSymbol.ImageUrl + "'>");            
        sbResult1.Append("<a href='http://" + strDomain + "/modules" + strURL + "'style='text-decoration:none;'>" + RootName + "&nbsp;" + "</a>");
        sbResult1.Append("<img src='" + ArrowSeparator.ImageUrl + "' hspace='10'>");

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        foreach (var item in ModuleList)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ModuleTitle"] != null)
            {                   
                if (item.ModuleTitle == HttpContext.Current.Session["ModuleTitle"].ToString() )
                {
                    //sbResult1.Append("<a href='http://" + strDomain + "/modules" + strURL + "?" + item.ModuleName + "'>" + item.ModuleTitle + "</a>" + Separator);

                    Separator3.ImageUrl = "/img/" + HttpContext.Current.Session["ModuleTitle"].ToString() + ".png";
                    sbResult1.Append("<img src='" + Separator3.ImageUrl + " 'hspace='10'>");
                    sbResult1.Append(HttpContext.Current.Session["ModuleTitle"]).ToString();
                }                               
            }
        }
        if (!ModuleList.Contains(HttpContext.Current.Session["ModuleTitle"]))
        {

            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ModuleTitle"] != null)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ModuleTitle"].ToString().Contains("_"))//|| HttpContext.Current.Session["ModuleSubTitle"] != null)
                {
                    string[] std = HttpContext.Current.Session["ModuleTitle"].ToString().Split('_');

                    Separator3.ImageUrl = "/img/" + std[0] + ".png";
                    sbResult1.Append("<img src='" + Separator3.ImageUrl + "' hspace='10'>");
                    sbResult1.Append("<a href='http://" + strDomain + "/modules" + strURL + "?" + std[0] + "'style='text-decoration:none;'>" + std[0] + "&nbsp;" + "</a>");
                    sbResult1.Append("<img src='" + ArrowSeparator.ImageUrl + "' hspace='10'>");

                    sbResult1.Append("<img src='/img/Prozess.png' hspace='10'>");

                    sbResult1.Append(std[1]);

                }

            }
        }

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------            

        output.Write(sbResult1.ToString());
    }
```

Do i have to make this Breadcrumb.cs and override Render() or is there a better way.

Greets DarkGecko

Answer (score 2):

have you considered a SiteMapPath?

```
<asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" Runat="server"></asp:SiteMapPath>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x20z8c51.aspx